# Nishita Sky texture not updating in all animation frames

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, shader-nodes, world

I’m rendering an animation of a night scene, where I’m using the Nishita Sky texture node to mimic a moon moving across the sky in a time lapse kind of way. For some reason it seems the sky texture/world doesn’t seem to update on every frame when I render the animation. The node’s elevation&rotation do change correctly when I move the playhead on the timeline but when I click on “Render animation” something goes wrong.

Un-checking persistent data seems to fix the problem but I don’t want to do that unless I absolutely have to, because it’s such a time saver when rendering. Is this a bug with the Sky texture, or just a limitation of using persistent data and if so how can I work around it?

I’m using Blender 3.6.2

The problem is visible on this gif or the video linked below. The sky texture/world stops updating for a frame or two but the camera moves normally.

[image]
https://youtu.be/g5lr05yv39Y